# React: Como enviar un dato a una API a través de un GET?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, get, frontend

Cree una barra de búsqueda, donde al seleccionar un usuario te redirige hacia su perfil. Otra persona creo una API donde hizo una función que recibe el id del usuario y devuelve toda su información, esta función es de tipo GET. Mi duda es: como envío el id a través de un GET?.

Esta es la función en la API:

```
export const searchbyID = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    //Funcion para traer al usuario seleccionado en el front mediante su ID
    
    const id = isNaN(req.query.id) ? false : req.query.id;
    const pool = await getConnection();
    const result = await pool
      .request()
      .input("iduser", sql.Int, id)
      .query(
        "SELECT u.iduser, u.name, u.surname, u.email, u.country, u.phone, u.profession, ISNULL(ch.userAzureID, 0) as userAzureID FROM userFigaruz u FULL JOIN chatCredentials ch ON ch.iduser = u.iduser WHERE u.iduser = @iduser"
      );

    const data = result.recordset;

    if(result.recordset.length >0 && id != false){
      const users = await USERS_ALL(data); 

      return res.status(200).json(users)
    }else{
      res.status(404).json({ message: 'Usuario no encontrado' })
    }
    
  }catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
    return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Ocurrio un error' });
  }
};
```

y aquí esta el hook en el front:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import UseFetchSearch from './UseFetchSearch';

const UseFetchSearchByID = () => {

    const [usersID, setUsersID] = useState([]);
    const endpoint = 'http://192.168.100.2:7000/search/user/id';
    const id = 87;
    const {users} = UseFetchSearch()
    const ic = users[0]

    const showData = async () => {
        const response = await fetch(endpoint);
        const data = await response.json();
        setUsersID(data);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        showData()
    }, []);
    
  return {usersID}
}

export default UseFetchSearchByID;
```

Creía que pasándole un id X a través de una instancia podría funcionar, pero no fue así. Esto fue lo que hice:

```
const {usersID} = UseFetchSearchByID(87);
    console.log(usersID)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luego de mucho investigar pude resolverlo, la única manera de enviar un parámetro como el id es añadiéndolo a la URL del endpoint, en mi caso el endpoint es el siguiente:

```
 const endpoint = 'http://192.168.100.2:7000/search/user/id'
```

para enviar el id, en este caso el 87, seria de la siguiente manera:

```
const endpoint = 'http://192.168.100.2:7000/search/user/id/?id=87';
```

Desconozco si se puede pasar mas de un parámetro.